# How to consider daylight savings time when using cron schedule in Airflow

Tags: airflow

In Airflow, I'd like a job to run at specific time each day in a non-UTC timezone. How can I go about scheduling this?

The problem is that once daylight savings time is triggered, my job will either be running an hour too soon or an hour too late. [In the Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/timezone.html), it seems like this is a known issue:

> In case you set a cron schedule, Airflow assumes you will always want
>   to run at the exact same time. It will then ignore day light savings
>   time. Thus, if you have a schedule that says run at end of interval
>   every day at 08:00 GMT+1 it will always run end of interval 08:00
>   GMT+1, regardless if day light savings time is in place.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there a work around? Surely the best practice cannot be to alter all the scheduled times after Daylight Savings Time occurs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with Airflow 1.10, time-zone aware DAGs can be defined using time-zone aware `datetime` objects to specify `start_date`. For Airflow to schedule DAG runs always at the same time (regardless of a possible daylight-saving-time switch), use cron expressions to specify `schedule_interval`. To make Airflow schedule DAG runs with fixed intervals (regardless of a possible daylight-saving-time switch), use `datetime.timedelta()` to specify `schedule_interval`.

For example, consider the following code that, first, uses a cron expression to schedule two consecutive DAG runs, and then uses a fixed interval to do the same.

```py
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

START_DATE = datetime(
    year=2019,
    month=10,
    day=25,
    hour=8,
    minute=0,
    tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('Europe/Kiev'),
)


def gen_execution_dates(start_date, schedule_interval):
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id='id', start_date=start_date, schedule_interval=schedule_interval
    )
    execution_date = dag.start_date
    for i in range(1, 3):
        execution_date = dag.following_schedule(execution_date)
        print(
            f'[Run {i}: Execution Date for "{schedule_interval}"]:',
            dag.timezone.convert(execution_date),
        )


gen_execution_dates(START_DATE, '0 8 * * *')
gen_execution_dates(START_DATE, timedelta(days=1))
```

Running the code produces the following output:

```
[Run 1: Execution Date for "0 8 * * *"]: 2019-10-26 08:00:00+03:00
[Run 2: Execution Date for "0 8 * * *"]: 2019-10-27 08:00:00+02:00
[Run 1: Execution Date for "1 day, 0:00:00"]: 2019-10-26 08:00:00+03:00
[Run 2: Execution Date for "1 day, 0:00:00"]: 2019-10-27 07:00:00+02:00
```

For the zone [Europe/Kiev], the daylight saving time of 2019 ends on 2019-10-27 at 03:00:00+03:00. That is, between Run 1 and Run 2 in our example.

The first two output lines show that for the DAG runs scheduled with a cron expression the first run and second run are both scheduled for 08:00 (although, in different timezones: Eastern European Summer Time (EEST) and Eastern European Time (EET) respectively).

The last two output lines show that for the DAG runs scheduled with a fixed interval the first run is scheduled for 08:00 (EEST), and the second run is scheduled exactly 1 day (24 hours) later, which is at 07:00 (EET) due to the daylight-saving-time switch.

The following figure illustrates the example:

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks. Is it possible to use this timezone / start_date on an ongoing basis? As in, to get the job to run continuously and not just as a one-off?

Comment: @ScottSkiles The default schedule is `schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(1)` (daily). You can redefine it as needed in `default_args`. E.g.: `schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(hours=1)` (hourly).

Comment: This correctly sets the start_date to the correct time zone, but the interval is not timezone-aware. It will increment 24 hours even if the correct increment is 23 hours or 25 hours.

Comment: @emote_control I have extended the answer to explain the difference between a crone and timedelta schedule.

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen on the entire web regarding this issue, Thank you so much.