# How to convert an Airflow DAG with cron schedule interval to run in America/New_York?

Tags: python, cron, airflow

I have a cronjob that runs with the cron schedule interval `05 */1 * * 1-5`. Or as [Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#05_*/1_*_*_1-5) says, “At minute 5 past every hour on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.” (in EST instead of UTC)?

**How can I convert this into a 'America/New_York' *timezone aware* Airflow DAG that will run the same exact way**?

I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668410/how-to-consider-daylight-savings-time-when-using-cron-schedule-in-airflow) on timezone aware DAGs in Airflow but it is not apparent to me in the answer or in the Airflow documentation how to make the jump from a DAG that has a `start_date` with `tzinfo` and a `schedule_interval`that mimics a cronjob.

I am currently trying to use a DAG with the `my_dag.py` file as follows:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/New_York")

default_args=dict(
    owner = 'airflow',
    start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 7, 13, 5, tzinfo=local_tz), # 1:05 PM on Nov 7
    schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1),
)

dag = DAG('my_test_dag', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)

op = BashOperator(
    task_id='my_test_dag',
    bash_command="bash -i /home/user/shell_script.sh",
    dag=dag
)
```

However, the DAG never gets scheduled. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow support the use of cron expressions. **schedule_interval** is defined as a DAG arguments, and receives preferably a cron expression as a str, or a datetime.timedelta object. Alternatively, you can also use one of these cron “preset”:None, @once, @hourly, @daily, @weekly  , @monthly, @yearly.

As I see, the timezone awareness is correct, but schedule interval should be change.

```
args=dict(
owner = 'airflow',
start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 7, 13, 5, tzinfo=local_tz), # 1:05 PM on Nov 7
)

dag=DAG(dag="dagname_here",
default_args=args,
schedule_interval='05 */1 * * 1-5' #should be string)
```

**NOTE**:  Please be reminded that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be triggered soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.

For reference: [Airflow Scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html?highlight=scheduling)

Comment: I attempted to edit the answer, but this does not work. `schedule_interval` needs to be defined under `DAG`.

Comment: Correct @ScottSkiles! I also put my schedule_interval on DAG. Thank you for noticing!